# Sources.list in Kali 2018

Tags: kali-linux

In Kali 2018 ,
I deleted it , after which I made it again by writing the 
.
But it's still not getting updated  .
What else should be written and why ?
What if i dont write (what if there is no sources. List in the system)

And it's doing ftp from some Taiwan center , how can I change it?

Answer (score 2):

From [the official Kali documentation](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories):

> kali-rolling is our current active repository since the release of Kali 2016.1. Kali Rolling users are expected to have the following entries in their `sources.list`:
>
> ```
> deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
> # For source package access, uncomment the following line
> # deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
> ```